# Is it possible to find out if an element comes before the second element in Capybara?

Tags: webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I was doing tests with `Caplybara`, `Cucumber` and `WebDriver`, so I looked at two elements on top of each other, so I thought.

- In a simpler way, is it possible to know if an element comes before the second?
- In a more complex way, is it possible to know if one element has a position on top of the other?

The structure is simple

```
<div id="father-parent">
    <p id="children-0">Firt element</p>
    <p id="children-1">Second element</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to verify is that children-0 comes right before children-1 you can use the CSS adjacent sibling selector

```
expect(page).to have_css('#children-0 + #children-1')
```

If you just want to verify that children-0 is a prior sibling of children-1 (not necessarily adjacent) you can use the general sibling selector

```
expect(page).to have_css('#children-0 ~ #children-1')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can do with simple content matching, I have just added a new matcher as `spec/support/matchers/appear_before_matcher.rb`:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :appear_before do |later_content|
  match do |earlier_content|
    page.body.index(earlier_content) < page.body.index(later_content)
  end
end
```

and then used it like this:

`expect('First element').to appear_before('Second element')`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the test is written, you could also use the [`have_sibling`](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/#have-sibling) matcher:

```rb
first_child = find('#children-0')
expect(first_child).to have_sibling('#children-1')
```

To test for element positions, some drivers support the [`:below` filter](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors):

```rb
expect(first_child).to have_sibling('#children-1', below: first_child)
```

`below` is one of [Capybara's global filters](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors), you could also use `above`, `left_of`, and `right_of`.